# Any way to have a 15 seconds rewind button in the jPlayer jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am using [this jPlayer plugin](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option) to have an audio player on my website.

Trying to get a function, assigned to a button, which rewinds the audio playback 15 seconds back from its current time position and continues to play.

Something similar to the button in the iPhone iTunes podcast player.

There is the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/18420/)

Essentially the code that I tried to run in the script area is the following.

```
$(".rewind").click(function(){
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", event.jPlayer.status.currentTime - 15); 
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `event.jPlayer.status.currentTime` is usually accessed when an event is raised by a `jPlayer` action. There are a couple work arounds to your problem, but the easiest might be just accessing the jPlayer `data` directly, as:

```
var currentTime = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data('jPlayer').status.currentTime;
```

Your updated code might look like this:

```
$(".rewind").click(function(e){
    var currentTime = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data('jPlayer').status.currentTime;
    if (currentTime > 15) {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", currentTime - 15);     
    }    
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/18423/

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're very close, but you don't have a 'jPlayer' event in a normal click handler and this [part of the jPlayer documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-data) states:

> The jPlayer object itself may also be accessed through $('#jp').data('jPlayer').

This JSFiddle is working with the change highlighted below:
http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/18422/

```
$(".rewind").click(function(event){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data('jPlayer').status.currentTime - 15); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it, storing the current time in a variable from the timeupdate event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current_time;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Bubble",
                m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3",
                oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
            });
        },
        timeupdate: function(e){
            current_time = e.jPlayer.status.currentTime;
        },
        swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });

    $(".rewind").on('click', function(e){
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer('play', current_time - 15);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/XLNCY/18424/)**

Comment: Thanks for helping out @kmsdev